# Why is it not drawing an outline?

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

so, i made an extra class called textlabel, because the normal windows forms label doesn't come with centered text, i also wanted to add an outline, but for some reason it doesn't draw the outline,
even though , outline is set to true, outlinewidth is equal to 10 and outline color is gray(backcolor is lightgray)

```
namespace mynamespace._2D
{
    public class TextLabel : Control,IDisposable
    {
        public bool Outline { get; set; } = true;
        public Color OutlineColor { get; set; } = Color.Gray;
        public int OutlineWidth { get; set; } = 10;
        public int Transparency { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool MultiLine { get; set; } = true;

        private System.Timers.Timer PaintTimer = new(120);
      //Constructor...
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Visible) return;
            Rectangle rectangle = new(Location,Size);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            if (Outline)
            {
                using Pen pen = new(OutlineColor, OutlineWidth);
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, new(Location, new Size(Size.Width - OutlineWidth, Size.Height - OutlineWidth)));
            }
            SizeF pixels = g.MeasureString(Text, Font);
            Point location = new(rectangle.Size.Width / 2 - (int)pixels.Width / 2, rectangle.Size.Height / 2-(int)pixels.Height/2);
            using Brush Textbrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);
            g.DrawString(Text, Font, Textbrush,location);
        }
     //rest of code...
    }
}
```

i tried overriding OnPaintbackground but that didn't help, it did the same thing as just doing everything in onpaint.
i tried debugging using console, but for some reason no console.writeline() actually pop up in the console :(

if i override onpaintbackground it just becomes a black box in the clientrectangle and nothing affects it, no backcolors, nothing else is drawn either, just a black box.
so i have stopped overriding onpaintbackground.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does support centered text, set the TextAlign property to TopCenter.  Either set the AutoSize property to False or set the MinimumSize

Comment: The issue with the "outline" is probably caused by the text overdrawing the rectangle.

Comment: This rectangle: `Rectangle rectangle = new(Location,Size);` is generated using the `Location` property, which is relative to the Parent. Use the Control's `ClientRectangle` to get the bounds of its internal surface. The same goes for the `DrawRectangle()` method, wrong coordinates

Comment: @Jimi , your answer worked!, i just wanted to say this so if other people have a problem like this, they know that this is the answer, for some reason i can't mark your comment as solution

Comment: Well, I can post that comment as an actual answer, if you want. But, can you clarify whether the Size specified in `g.DrawRectangle(pen, new(Location, new Size(Size.Width - OutlineWidth, Size.Height - OutlineWidth)));` is actually what you want. It doesn't seem, let's say, *correct* -- What's the threaded Timer for?

Comment: @Jimi , you said that the rectangle generated using : `Rectangle rectangle = new(Location,Size);` was wrong, and that i should use the client rectangle instead, so i did. i replaced all Size and Locations with ClientRectangle.Size and ClientRectangle.Location, that made it work!  also the PaintTimer is just this: `PaintTimer.Elapsed += (sender,e) => Invalidate()` to update the appearance if anything changes.

Comment: Nope, it was about what you're subtracting here: `new(Location, new Size(Size.Width - OutlineWidth, Size.Height - OutlineWidth)` (of course you have changed those measures using the ClientRectangle): note that `DrawRectangle()` draws the lines in the middle of the rectangle's bounds (half inside, half outside) -- You cannot have that timer there: it's a threaded Timer, it cannot interact with the UI Thread. Anyway, this is not how this stuff works. You have to use the Properties' setters to invalidate the canvas when the new value affects the graphic, so `OnPaint()` is called.

Comment: so like this: 
        public bool Outline
        {
            get { return outline; }
            set { outline = value; Invalidate(); }
        } also i forgot to tell you, but when i changed the values i also added some calculations to the location to draw the outline correctly: `g.DrawRectangle(pen, new(new(ClientRectangle.Location.X+ OutlineWidth/2 ,ClientRectangle.Location.Y+OutlineWidth/2), new(ClientRectangle.Size.Width - OutlineWidth, ClientRectangle.Size.Height - OutlineWidth))); `

Comment: Yep, that's just how it works. Properties that `Invalidate()` the canvas need a backing Field, just check that the new value is different from the old one, so you don't invalidate for no reason (it's heavy work, heavier when you have collections of these controls on a Form). What's important is that you remove that Timer. When you need a Timer, use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, its Tick event is raised in the UI Thread

Comment: will this use more or less memory? when using setters and getters? also do control's inherited properties automatically invalidate when set , or do i have to make setters for it aswell?

Comment: It's not about the memory used, it's about how much and how often the graphics of a Form needs to be refreshed. That's the heaviest work of the underlying graphic engine. You always want to avoid flickering of any kind -- The behavior of the Properties of a standard Control are handled in different ways. Mostly, controlled by the underlying [LayoutEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.layout.layoutengine) and the Control's Designer (almost all Controls have a dedicated Designer and a specialized LayoutEngine)